# Active Record Validations: Uniqueness of a calculated field while inserting it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with a calculated field that must be unique:

```rb
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
 before_save :set_unique_identifier

 validates :unique_identifier, uniqueness: true

 private

 def set_unique_identifier
    some calculation...
    self.unique_identifier = the calculations.. (THIS IS A STRING)
 end

end
```

Active Record is letting me to create the records having the same unique_identifier.

The `validates :unique_identifier, uniqueness: true` is being triggered only when I update the record.

How to validate it in the moment of insertion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving an ActiveRecord model does things in this order:

1. Run `before_validation` hooks.
2. Run validations.
3. Run `before_save` hooks
4. Save.

There's more going on of course but these are the relevant parts.

I don't think changing an attribute in step **3** is guaranteed to rerun validations in step **2**.

I think you want to set the unique identifier in a `before_validation` hook rather than a `before_save` hook:

```
class MyModel < ApplicationRecord
  before_validation :set_unique_identifier
  ...
end
```

This way everything will happen in the right order.

You'd also want to include a unique constraint/index in your database to really ensure that you don't get duplicates.

Comment: About the constrain I did like that but i'm not sure the syntax its correct.
My migration: `t.string  :unique_identifier, null: false, index: true`

Comment: Add another migration to remove the existing index (`remove_index :my_models, :unique_identifier`) and then add a unique index (`add_index :my_models, :unique_identifiers, unique: true`).